# Contextual Lazy-loading in Datamapper - how?

Tags: lazy-loading, datamapper

The Datamapper documentation does a great job of telling me how to set up contextual lazy loading [here](http://datamapper.org/articles/spotlight_on_laziness.html) but unfortunately it doesn't tell me how to actually pass the context in record retrievals.

I imagine it would be something like so:

```
id = 10
hotel = Hotel.get(id, :context => :detailed)
```

or something like that. Can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a lazy property is read, all properties in the same context are loaded in the same query. There's no other ways to specify a context. Maybe you should patch Datamapper or write a feature request.